# Quiero comprobar si un elemento del array existe

Tags: javascript

Quiero saber si existe este indice en mi array para ello realizo la siguiente comprobación.

```
if (typeof platos2[diaActual]['nombre']['Cena'][1] !== 'undefined')
   {
       cena1 = platos2[diaActual]['nombre']['Cena'][1];
   }
```

Pero me da el siguiente error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined`  que es lo que quiero saber si exite obtengo el valor si no no hago nada.

Yo quiero comprobar si el contenido de ese indice es igual a algo si no si , existe ese indice en mi array

Comment: undefined sin comillas: typeof platos2[diaActual]['nombre']['Cena'][1] !== undefined

Comment: El error lo que te esta diciendo es que `platos2[diaActual]['nombre']['Cena']` es `undefined`. Si te fijas te dice que `Cannot read property '1' of undefined`.

Comment: @toto, las comillas estan bien, esta usando `typeof x`, el cual devuelve un `string`

Comment: Gracias marcos por la corrección. Mea culpa por la distracción.